# How to add a close button to jQuery push side panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Sidr plugin for a side panel, sample of html:

```
       <ul>
       <li><a href="#" id="edinburgh-menu">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="glasgow-menu">Two</a></li>
       </ul>

       <div id="edinburgh-div" style="display:none;">
       this is content
       </div>

       <div id="glasgow-div" style="display:none;">
       this is content 
       </div>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edinburgh-menu').sidr({name: 'Edinburgh-menu',source: '#edinburgh-div'});    
$('#glasgow-menu').sidr({name: 'Glasgow-menu',source: '#glasgow-div'});});
```

This makes the side panel open.

How can I add a button/link, inside both panels, that would make them close?

http://jsfiddle.net/0feug6g9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this fiddle works,

http://jsfiddle.net/0feug6g9/7/

I made some modifications to your original code. What I have done is:

1. Created a close button with class 'close-sidr' in both the menu.
2. Sidr library appends its own class i think, so the modified class becomes 'sidr-class-close-sidr'.
3. Then i created click event for the close buttons, which closes any open side menu. The syntax for this is $.sidr('close', 'menu name here');

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.sidr-class-close-sidr', function() {
     $.sidr('close', 'Edinburgh-menu');
     $.sidr('close', 'Glasgow-menu');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Open/Close Programatically** 
There are some methods you can use to open or close menus as you want, or to bind them to any event. For example, in this page the right/left swipe touch event opens or closes the responsive menu (Note: this plugin doesn't implement touch events, in this case I'm using an external library).

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="edinburgh-menu">Open</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="close-sidr-menu">Close [x]</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="edinburgh-div" style="display:none;"> 
    <p>Your content here.</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edinburgh-menu').sidr({name: 'Edinburgh-menu',source: '#edinburgh-div'});
    $(document).on('click', '#close-sidr-menu', function() {
        $.sidr('close', 'Edinburgh-menu');
        $.sidr('close', 'Glasgow-menu');
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle for your answer** - http://jsfiddle.net/antonoff/0feug6g9/9/ 
**Reference** - http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#documentation 
**Demo code** - https://gist.github.com/artberri/6da9f659b77b028e3caa#file-programatically-sample-sidr-html

Comment: Tibbers, I went through the docs, please note I am a beginner, and this is me practicing, could you be more specific?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/antonoff/0feug6g9/6/ It's a bit glitching and closing the menu only from second attempt, but still it's working. Improve it and use it. Good luck!

Comment: @user3836044 I've fully updated the answer. Provided working answer + Reference. Good luck hope it will help.